# Wildfly many domains with many ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildfly

I've got test server and I would like to run many applications on that instance, but there's a problem with SSL certificates. If I'm using single certificate, everything is ok, but if when I add another, there is a problem.

This is my ssl realm configuration :

```
<security-realm name="ssl-realm">
    <server-identities>
        <ssl>
            <keystore path="cert_one.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="1234" key-password="1234"/>
            <keystore path="cert_two.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="1234" key-password="1234"/>
        </ssl>
    </server-identities>
</security-realm>
```

And this is my undertow server configuration:

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
    <https-listener name="defaultHttps" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ssl-realm" max-post-size="31457280"/>
    <host name="one_app" alias="firstapp.com">                    
        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
    <host name="two_app" alias="secondapp.com">               
        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
</server>
```

As you can see I have two different certificate keystores, one for firstapp.com and another for secondapp.com.

But only certificate for secondapp.com is working. If I delete one of those keystores everything is OK. How to configure two or more certificates for different domains in Wildfly configuration?

Comment: do you fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WildFly multiple domains and SSL certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413682/wildfly-multiple-domains-and-ssl-certificates)